# Is there any other technique which can be used to replace rss feed syndication technique?

Tags: rss

I want some other technique to add automatic updates to my web page other than rss feed technique?

Answer (score 0):

Automatic updates from where? 3rd party sites? You'll have to eitehr scrape their HTML or ask them to suppport another syndication format...